# How to automate taking new image every time I make a change to an AWS instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services

So , me and my colleagues make relatively frequent changes to an AWS instance (adding a user, creating a new group etc).

I have this instance inside an AutoScalingGroup , so everytime I make a change I have to create a new AMI and modify the LaunchConfiguration.

Do you have any solution on making this procedure quicker and maybe more automated?

I was thinking of implementing at some point the concept of infrastructure as code and introduce Packer, but for now I am searching for something in between.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there would be a possibility for our launch configuration to autoupdate AMI dynamically.

U would need to create the automation stuff yourself. U can either use custom bash script that u can run after your changes. Or configure aws lambda to perform these tasks on the event that new AMI was created.

Answer (score 0):

You could define your stack in a CloudFormation template. Your changes can be captured in the user-data or cloud init. This way your changes can be put under source control and achieve infrastructure as code. (As you mentioned, Packer would also work but it can only define a single instance. With CloudFormation you can describe your complete AWS stack.)